# Does this loop skip the first row when returning MYSQL array for FPDF?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

Does the following code leads to skip the first record of mysql array when using with fpdf?

```
$data=array();
while ($row_orders = mysql_fetch_assoc($orders)){
    $data[]= $row_orders;
}
return $data;
```

Comment: Uhm, no ... what is your query?

Comment: Is this a poll ? Is there any issues ?

Comment: i forgot to add the following code before $data variable:

Comment: `$orders = mysql_query($query_orders, $server) or die(mysql_error());
$row_orders = mysql_fetch_assoc($orders);`

Comment: Note that php's "mysql_" functions are deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FPDF does not matter here, this code does not use it directly.

This code get all data results to an indexed array, it does not skip the first row, if this one is missing, check you are not calling mysql_fetch_assoc($orders) before this code.

The best way to know is to try.

Comment: thanks it works! i just recognize that i called mysql_fetch_assoc before the code.

Comment: the force is strong in this one